# Passing errors through login-config to form-error-page with JBOSS

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, ldap, login-config.xml

I'm making a correction in an app of my company that uses JBOSS 4.2.

The change is in login page. 
We use login-config that connects to AD server using LDAP.

Works fine, but the problem is if the user account is expired or AD is offline or something else, the user will see a error page describing that "username/password is invalid" because the method of login-config returns a boolean that only means connected or not.

below is the actual login config

```
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule" flag="requisite">
            <module-option name="password-stacking">useFirstPass</module-option>
            <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</module-option>
            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url">ldaps://XXXXX</module-option>
            <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication">simple</module-option>
            <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords">false</module-option>
            <module-option name="principalDNPrefix">XXX</module-option>
            <module-option name="principalDNSuffix">,XXXXX</module-option>
            <module-option name="matchOnUserDN">true</module-option>
        </login-module>
```

And the web-security xml

```
    <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>    
    <form-login-config>     
      <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/login.jsp?invalidLogin=true</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

The question is: I want to show to the user what happened if an error occurs, example, if his account is inactive, I don't want to show "username/password invalid"

I made a custom class to handle login-config, called here Login, then the  changes

```
<login-module code="package.Login" flag="requisite">
```

with this I can get the LDAP erros, but I can't pass to login error page, because the method that valid login is boolean:

below the method that JBOSS call to verify credentials:

```
  /** Validate the inputPassword by creating a ldap InitialContext with the
    SECURITY_CREDENTIALS set to the password.

    @param inputPassword the password to validate.
    @param expectedPassword ignored
    */
   protected boolean validatePassword(String inputPassword, String     expectedPassword)
   {

    }
```

Finally, it's possible to return custom errors messages to login-form error? Can be a workaround, since I have read that login-config does not provide a standard way to do this.

Comment: From a security perspective, you do not want to add additional information. You should be as generic as possible. I've personally used additional information from login failed error messages to enumerate and gain access to user accounts during security testing.

Comment: @Casey yes, i know this, but let's say just for curiosity, is there a workaround for that? Thank you.

Comment: A work around for not adding additional information?

Comment: @Casey basically yes, I want to add more some information than just true/false

Answer (score 0):

I have done this once, but I cannot seem to find the code snippet anymore. 
What I recall, is that I had to call `getValidateError()` if the password check failed.

Something along the lines of

```
if ( validatePassword( pwd, null ) )
{
    // yeah
}
else
{
    Throwable e = getValidateError();
    // Now you can query the throwable for the cause and message
}
```

Let me know if this did not get you anywhere ;-)

Comment: I know if the validatePassword fails it means an error, but my problem is how to add some information about the error to pass through the form-error-page. Your code is inside java class that handle the login process, but I need to pass to jsp that is called after validatePassword fails. JBOSS is who call validatePassword and I can't change the process that call this method, I can only change the code inside validatePassword.